# $\cosh^4x-\sinh^4x=\cosh2x$

Tags: trigonometry, hyperbolic-functions

I need to show that $\cosh^4(x)-\sinh^4(x) = \cosh(2x)$

First I found myself going in circles..

$$\cosh (2 x)=\frac{1}{2} \left(e^{-2 x}+e^{2 x}\right)= \sinh(2x)$$

Now I'm trying to get somewhere using the identity $$\cosh ^2(x)-\sinh ^2(x)=1$$

if $\cosh ^2(x)-\sinh ^2(x)=1$ then $$\cosh ^2(x)-\sinh ^2(x)=\left(\frac{1}{2} \left(e^{-x}+e^x\right)\right)^2-\left(\frac{1}{2} \left(e^x-e^{-x}\right)\right)^2$$

yet the same doesn't apply when I take them to the $4^\text{th}$ power.

Please could someone point me in the right direction as I'm getting very lost here.

Comment: Please consider using \cosh and \sinh to get $\cosh$ and $\sinh$ instead of cosh and sinh which give $cosh$ and $sinh$.

Comment: To "Fly by Night"'s comment I would add that the backslash not only prevents italicization but also results in proper spacing in things like $a\cosh b$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**: Factor $$ (\cosh x )^4 -(\sinh x)^4  = ((\cosh x )^2 -(\sinh x)^2 )(\cosh x )^2 +(\sinh x)^2 )  \\= (\cosh x )^2 +(\sinh x)^2  $$

and then use identites for $\cosh(2x)$

Answer (score 4):

HINT: You know that

$$\begin{align*}
\cosh^4x-\sinh^4x&=\left(\cosh^2x-\sinh^2x\right)\left(\cosh^2x+\sinh^2x\right)\\
&=\cosh^2x+\sinh^2x\\
&=\left(\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}2\right)^2+\left(\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}2\right)^2\;;
\end{align*}$$

can you finish it from there?

Comment: doesn't $(\frac{e^x + e^-x}{2})^2 + \frac{e^x - e^-x}{2})^2 = 2cosh(2x)$? @Brian M. Scott

Comment: @Mathsguy9020: No, it's $$\frac{1}{4}\left(e^{2x}+2+e^{-2x}+e^{2x}-2+e^{-2x}\right)=\frac{e^{2x}+e^{-2x}}2=\cosh 2x\;.$$

Answer (score 2):

the left hand side is given by 
$$2e^{2x}+2e^{-2x}$$ and the right hand side is $$2e^{2x}+2e^{-2x}$$
thus our equation is true for all real $$x$$